# Estimating the variance of noise in an image with Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, noise

Within Matlab I'm adding noise to an image with a known variance. I know that I can do that with the following:

```
var = 0.01;
i   = im2double(imread('lena.bmp'));
i_n = imnoise(i, 'gaussian',0,var);
```

Clearly the resulting image has noise. However if I try to estimate the noise variance by calculating the median of a high pass filter, I'm really not seeing any correlation

```
k = [1 4 6 4 1]'*[1 4 6 4 1];
kk = k ./sum(sum(k));

var_est = median(median(abs(i_n - imfilter(i_n,kk))))

   var_est(:,:,1) =

   0.0631


   var_est(:,:,2) =

   0.0620


   var_est(:,:,3) =

   0.0625
```

I appreciate estimating the variance is a difficult problem, but I just want to get a reasonably close result, e.g. 50% error is tolerable. What am I doing incorrect?

Comment: I'm not sure that this formula is really what you need. Can you provide a source where you found it? Was it in a paper?

Comment: @Phonon - I'm looking for a reference now, I'm pretty certain I read it in a paper a while back. Intuitively I thought it makes sense, i.e. after the high pass filtering you're left with noise and edge detail, as noise dominates in quantity, the median should be a reasonable estimate of the noise variance

Comment: aha I realised what the problem was... there should be an additional scaling factor of 1/0.675 - that then gives a very reasonable esimtate of 0.00926

Comment: So you got it working? You should post it as an answer if you did so that other people could come along and look at it.

Comment: @Phonon it doesn't always seem to give reasonable answers - so I'll wait to see if anyone else has comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach results inadequate in this case, since when using imnoise you're really adding an approximated version of white noise, which exhibits components at all frequencies. When using a high-pass filter you're clipping frequency components of the noise, thus reducing the accuracy of your estimation.

Indeed noise estimation from only one image, as you mentioned, is not a simple problem. However there are some approaches, for example you can use [median absolute deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation) that lets you obtain and approximation for the dispersion on your data (in this case for the pixel intensities under your kernel)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your explanation makes sense to me. However I'm still not sure about the answer I get. Assuming I understood you correctly I did the following:  i_median(:,:,1) = medfilt2(i_n(:,:,1)); i_median(:,:,2) = medfilt2(i_n(:,:,2)); i_median(:,:,3) = medfilt2(i_n(:,:,3)); var_est = median(median(median(abs(i_n - i_median)))). This gives an answer of 0.0590 - this doesn't seem correct either?

Answer (score 1):

You can take calculate variance of the high pass filtered image.  Don't use `var` for your variable name because it's the name of the Matlab function which calculates variance.

```
v = var; % use v instead of var for your variance variable
clear var; % clear your variable "var" so we can use the var function
est_variance = var(reshape(i_n - imfilter(i_n,kk), [], 1));
```

Comment: thanks for the response kristi - I'm clearly doing something wrong as when I try the above I'm getting est_variance = 199.0065 ?!? The only change is that I'm opening the image in uint8 and only doing a double conversion prior to the variance command, i.e.  est_variance = var(double(reshape(i_n - imfilter(i_n,kk), [], 1))).  That said I've retried it using the im2double as above, and I get  0.0085. which is about right, particularly considering the point that @msotaquira made above.